# Teams App - External API authentication and data storage best practices

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm working on a message extension task module with embedded web view that is invoked from the "..." overflow menu on a message.  When the user first launches my task module, I would like to have the user provide user name/password into a login screen hosted in the web view, which will be sent to my REST API, and a token will be returned and used for subsequent operations in the web view.

What are the best practices for storing the token for making those additional requests?  I don't want to require the user to sign into my API each time they launch my task module embedded web view.  Is there a solution for this in Teams JS?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest rather using SSO for this - it's built in and way more secure than storing your own usernames + passwords. See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview